# C# XML Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, annotations

I've got an xml file with such structure:

```
<panel>
<tr>
    <td>
            <element>
                ... smth
            </element>
    </td>
    <td>
            <element>
                ... smth
            </element>
    </td>
    <td>
            <element>
                ... smth
            </element>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
            <element>
                ... smth
            </element>
    </td>
    <td>
            <element>
                ... smth
            </element>
    </td>
</tr>
</panel>
```

This is my object structure:

```
public class Panel
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName="tr")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="td")]
    public List<tr> Tr { get; set; }

}
public class tr
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName="tr")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="td")]
    public List<td> td { get; set; }
}

public class td
{
    public Element Element { get; set; }
}
```

After deserialization I have Panel with 5 tr class objects. Can you help me to correct annotations

Comment: I suppose you meant to put a closing "</panel>" tag in the XML section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work (the contents for the "Element" class are not specified in your example, I just made a string of it):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="panel")]
public class Panel
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("tr")]
    public List<Tr> tr { get; set; }
}

public class Tr
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("td")]
    public List<Td> td { get; set; }
}

public class Td
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("element")]
    public Element Element { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText]
    public string prop { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it works perfect. Thank you! I've changed XmlElementAttribute to XmlElement

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be..

```
public class Panel
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName="panel")] //instead of [XmlArray(ElementName="tr")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="tr")]
    public List<tr> Tr { get; set; }
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whole code for your serialization:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var lst = new List<Td>();

        var p = new Panel();
        p.Tr = new List<tr>();
        var tr = new tr();
        p.Tr.Add(tr);
        tr.td = new List<Td>();
        tr.td.Add(new Td() { Element = "Val1" });
        tr.td.Add(new Td() { Element = "Val2" });

        var xmlRel = SerializeObject(p);


        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ser.xml", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.Write(xmlRel);
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();


    }

    public static String SerializeObject(Object pObject)
    {
        try
        {
            String XmlizedString = null;
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Panel));
            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, pObject);
            memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
            XmlizedString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            return XmlizedString;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String UTF8ByteArrayToString(Byte[] characters)
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        String constructedString = encoding.GetString(characters);
        return (constructedString);
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "panel")]
public class Panel
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("tr")]
    public List<tr> Tr { get; set; }

}
public class tr
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("td")]
    public List<Td> td { get; set; }
}


public class Td
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("element")]
    public string Element { get; set; }
}

}
```